# Yesod Forms or JSON/Ajax or Other

Tags: haskell, yesod, aeson

I'm writing a CRUD interface for my Yesod-based site, but I'm having a problem with some values.  In particular, I am trying to CRUD on values like:

```
data Value = Value { valueId :: UUID
                   , otherStuff :: Stuff
                   }
```

I am having trouble figuring out a good way to create one of these using the tools Yesod and Aeson provide.  When I used formlets, in the distant past, I would use the monad transformer version of the form to do something along the lines of:

```
Value <$> (liftIO getUUID)
      <*> textField Nothing
```

(I'm probably not getting the formlets syntax exactly right, but hopefully the Haskellers out there get the gist).  This had the effect of making a form that did not include a UUID field and a form parser that ran the IO action to make the data at post-time.

I'm not sure how to proceed.  I considered the same kind of idea with Aeson parsing, but attoparsec (the underlying parser) is not a monad transformer either.

Can anybody think of any more options other than having an intermediate data representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is call an IO action in an Applicative form, there is a trick you can use:

```
lift (liftIO action)
```

The issue is that an Applicative can't be an instance of MonadIO, but it can be an instance of MonadTrans.